# Android - Refactor network requests

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, refactoring, android-volley

Let's take two generic methods:

1. `fooA()`, which `onSuccess`, it updates activity `A`
2. `fooB()`, which `onSuccess` invokes `fooA()`

that send an asynchronous Volley request each to my server.

I would like to avoid in Activity `A` this pattern:

```
class A : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_A)
        
        fooB()
    }

    fun fooB(): {
        volleyRequest() {
               onSuccess(): fooA()
               onFailure(): Log.e("ERROR")
        }
    }

    fun fooA(): {
         volleyRequest() {
               onSuccess(): // do something on UI
               onFailure(): Log.e("ERROR")
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, I would like to keep my code clean and define these requests in a separate `RequestManager` and have something like:

```
class A : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_A)

            RequestManager.fooB().onSuccess().RequestManager.fooA().onSuccess() {
                // do something on UI
            }
        }
    }
```

Separating methods in this way would allow me to reuse `fooA()` and `fooB()` in other ways throughout my application.
Is it possible in Android (Kotlin) to deal with asynchronous tasks in this way?

Comment: coroutines, rxjava might help you out

Comment: Thank you! I guess that I was searching [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005491/android-asynchronous-network-calls-response-dependent-on-each-other) scenario